# If G is a nonabelian group with order of $p^3$ which p is a prime number then prove $G’=Z(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I have an exam in two hours and this is one of the exercises in my textbook that I have problem with, I tried solving it using the main theorems but i couldn’t figure it out.
The question goes:

If G is a nonabelian group with order of $p^3$ which p is a prime number then prove $G’=Z(G)$

A hint or an answer would be appreciated .

Comment: You don't know what the assumed background is, but a proof is part of Lemma 1 on the first page of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/groupsp3.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a $p$-group, the center is nontrivial. The center cannot have prime index, since $G/Z(G)$ cannot be cyclic nontrivial; and the center cannot be of order $p^3$, because then $G$ would be abelian. Thus, $|Z(G)|=p$.

Now, $G/Z(G)$ is of order $p^2$ and hence abelian. Thus, $[G,G]\leq Z(G)$. But $Z(G)$ is of prime order, so either $[G,G]$ is trivial or $[G,G]=Z(G)$. But $G$ is nonabelian, so $[G,G]\neq\{e\}$. Thus, $[G,G]=Z(G)$.